# Vue: return filtered list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, v-for

I have an api which returns the following categories and attributes: [image]

No I try to render a list of the attribute_name of each category.
The result should look something like this, but I need checkboxes instead of radio buttons: [image]

I tried to filter the attributes from the category_id but it doesn't work.
With the following code I just get a list of all the attributes

```
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="category in categories"
      v-bind:key="category.name"
    >
      <p
        v-for="attributes in category.attributes"
        :key="attributes.attribute_name"
      >{{ attributes.attribute_name }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Does anyone has an idea how I could filter these attributes into their categories?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Mind if you could create a sandbox and add your code, So that It is easier to understand and answer it. If you like you can use codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what I think you want. If it is not please try to clarify what you need.

```
<ul v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name">
  {{category.category_name}}
  <li
    v-for="attributes in category.attributes"
    :key="attributes.attribute_name"
  >
  <input type="checkbox" :id="attributes.attribute_name">
    <label :for="attributes.attribute_name">
      {{ attributes.attribute_name }}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much! You solved my problem :)